# How to concat a list of dataframes depending on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes:

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
```

And each dataframe looks like this:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[2020-02,2020-01],['PC','PC'],[0.6,1.4],[0.5,1.3]], columns=['Date', 'platform', "Day 1","Day 7"])

df2=pd.DataFrame([[2020-02,2020-01],['Mobile','Mobile'],[0.6,1.4],[0.5,1.3]], columns=['Date', 'platform', "Day 1","Day 7"])

df3=pd.DataFrame([[2020-03,2020-04],['PC','PC'],[0.6,1.4],[0.5,1.3]], columns=['Date', 'platform', "Day 1","Day 7"])

df4=pd.DataFrame([[2020-03,2020-04],['Mobile','Mobile'],[0.6,1.4],[0.5,1.3]], columns=['Date', 'platform', "Day 1","Day 7"])
```

I want to concat those dataframes inside the list that have the same platform value. In this case, I would need to concat df1 + df3 and df2 + df4.

I have tried this:

```
df_new = pd.concat(dfs[1], dfs[3])
```

But it returns the following error message:

```
first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Do you know any way to concat those dataframes with the same platform name from the list without creating only one dataframe and then filter it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
 pd.concat([list_df[0], list_df[2]])
 pd.concat([list_df[1], list_df[3]])
```

---

```
platform_list = []
for _, g in pd.concat(list_df).groupby(['platform']):
    platform_list.append(g)
```

Comment: I still need both dataframes separately inside the list. This code is just puting all together on the same dataframe and that's no exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @matmataHi Are looking for `[[df1, df3],[df2,d4]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df_new = pd.concat([dfs[1], dfs[3]])
```